# How Can I Make My Touchscreen Shifting More Smooth Like This Game (Sky Rusher)?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, mobile

This is what I am trying to replicate:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K9b7h77Ukcy5FulEX3pi9pHShyhpdmVT

I am trying to make my movement ore like this for a mobile app I am working on with a space ship. I made a basic script that moves it around the screen when I swipe left and right and also rotates it, and when I stop moving my finger it moves it back, but it looks very different even though I feel like I am having the same idea as this game in the recording (Sky Rusher). I am very new to Unity so any and all help is appreciated! I ran this on Unity 2018.3.6 and on an iPhone. This was attached to a very simple paper plane model that was placed on an origin with a camera directly behind it because I wanted to get the movement down first. Thanks ahead of time!
Below is my code and if this helps, this is a link to my project uploaded to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mcx2FzR6zDFdvBWFnumoVQBKmq56ngVw)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.iOS;

public class ObjectShifter : MonoBehaviour
{
private Vector3 position;
private float width;
private float height;
private float shiftSpeed;
private float sideRotationAmount;
private float verticalRotationAmount;
private Quaternion rotation;

void Awake()
{
    shiftSpeed = 5f;
    sideRotationAmount = 0f;
    verticalRotationAmount = 0f;
    width = (float)Screen.width / 2.0f;
    height = (float)Screen.height / 2.0f;

    // Position used for the cube.
    position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
}

void Update()
{
    // Handle screen touches.
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        Vector2 currentPos = touch.position;

        if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) || (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && touch.deltaPosition.magnitude < 1.5))
        {
            shiftBack();
        }
        else
        {
            Vector2 pos = touch.position;
            pos.x = 3 * (pos.x - width) / width;
            pos.y = 6 * (pos.y - height) / height;
            sideRotationAmount = -15 * pos.y;
            verticalRotationAmount = -5 * pos.x;
            position = new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y, 0.0f);
            transform.position = position;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        shiftBack();
    }
    rotation = Quaternion.Euler(sideRotationAmount, verticalRotationAmount, verticalRotationAmount);
    transform.rotation = rotation;
}

void shiftBack()
{
    if(verticalRotationAmount > 0)
    {
        verticalRotationAmount -= (verticalRotationAmount%shiftSpeed);
        verticalRotationAmount-=shiftSpeed;
    }
    else if(verticalRotationAmount < 0)
    {
        verticalRotationAmount -= (verticalRotationAmount%shiftSpeed);
        verticalRotationAmount+=shiftSpeed;
    }
    if(sideRotationAmount > 0)
    {
        sideRotationAmount -= (sideRotationAmount%shiftSpeed);
        sideRotationAmount-=shiftSpeed;
    }
    else if(sideRotationAmount < 0)
    {
        sideRotationAmount -= (sideRotationAmount%shiftSpeed);
        sideRotationAmount+=shiftSpeed;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The first drive link is not public. We see the "request permission" page when we open it. Try your link in Chorme's incognito mode.

Comment: @GazihanAlankus Sincerest apologies! This link should work: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mcx2FzR6zDFdvBWFnumoVQBKmq56ngVw

Comment: Did you have a video in the link where you say "This is what I am trying to replicate"? We can't see that one.

Comment: @GazihanAnkalus apologies once again, I updated the post so the link sharing works properly. The game is called Sky Rusher.